# Connection to a database

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector

How do i connect visual studio c++ 2010 to my sql database and transfer information?

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

Should i type a program for this?

Comment: Do you mean your sql database or MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full integration with Visual Studio 2010 is available only with [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) 6.3.2 and up, although applications using earlier versions of the connector can be built with the Visual Studio 2010 environment using .NET 2.x frameworks.

Once you have installed the connector follow the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html)

Comment: You welcome, if this answers your question please consider accepting this or one of any following answers by clicking the V on the left side of the answer.